# Visual Studio set Project Url in build event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've got a project that runs from different urls depending on the currently selected build configuration.

For example if my build configuration is set to `Debug` the project url needs to be `http://www.myproject.dev`, if my build configuration is set to `DebugUSA` the project url needs to be set to `http://www.myprojectusa.dev`.

Unfortunately VS2013 doesn't allow you to have a separate project url for each build configuration.  It just uses the same url regardless of which configuration you have selected.

Is there a way of setting the project url from a build event script?

If this isn't possible using build events, is there another way I can achieve the same result?

**EDIT**: [Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EPpB.png) to show you the setting that I'd like to modify.

Comment: What do you mean by "Set Project Url"? Are you talking about when you **start debugging**, the page it opens up in the browser?

Comment: Right click on a Web Application, click properties, then select Web.  It's the "Project Url" setting underneath servers.  It's used to tell Visual Studio which site to attach the debugger to.  Here's a picture of the setting screen so you can see what I mean http://i.stack.imgur.com/6EPpB.png

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar (same?) question been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021889/61697), although I'm not sure if it will help you in your case. Other than having some funky post-build event to modify the .csproj file or .csproj.user file, it doesn't look like there's anything you can do.